# Turn equation numbering to arabic letters in IEEEtran

Tags: equations, ieeetran, sections-paragraphs

The IEEEtran uses latin numbers for sections, i.e., I. Introduction.... Consequently, the equation numbering is of the form (I.1), (I.2), (II.1), (II.2).... 
How do i turn this numbering to ordinary (1.1), (1.2), (2.1), (2.2)?

Comment: in preamble: `\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}`? Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Also: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Zarko forgot a `}` at the end of his code, please  again with it!

Comment: `\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}` works.  Latest version of IEEEtran is v1.8b.  Which one are you using?

Comment: Let mi repeat my first comment, where I forgot on one curly brace (CarLaTReX, thank you; now we can close this question as "solved by comments" :-) ) ... in preamble: `\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}‌}​`? Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by comments.